# Testing without affected certain tables

Tags: mysql, cakephp, testing

At the moment I'm stuck with the need to debug several functions in our system to determine if they're working or not.

The situation is basicly that I'm left with someone elses CakePHP structure which makes me unable to know the code in and out. This is due to lack of time and lack of documentation.

I need to run tests on this system, however it will cause incorrect data on our reports page when I create new orders etc. This is not allowed and basicly there's a lot of models which saves data to the reports by simply creating other rows.

The easiest solution here would be to make no report rows get created if I'm logged in as a certain user. Then I'd simply just do a condition and determine if I should insert the report row in the database or not. (`if ($bool_tester) return FALSE; else /* Insert data */`)
This would however require to fetch the Session data within the Model, which I've read is a bad solution. I can't simply run an extra parameter in the function, since the function is called on so many places in so many files.

So my question is basicly; Should I include Session data within the Model regardless or is there any other nifty solution that makes me not insert these rows when I'm testing.

Defining a session value through the controllers isn't a smooth solution either here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the testing in your development environment, not on the live site.

Comment: Have none, and haven't gotten used to using one either due to time pressures. If I copied all of the structure to a test enviroment, I believe I would create more errors by simply forgetting to update the things I try on the test enviroment to the live site.

Comment: Not having a test environment isn't going to put you under less time pressure. Hugely false economy. Setting up an effective one is an initial hit, but the route you have chosen isn't a valid test of anything. Once you start adding code that only works in test mode, you are testing that not your live code. Bite the bullet, invest in it, it will repay just on not risking the live system, never mind getting something wrong, and wrecking the live system.

Comment: The use of a test enviroment is depending on quiet some factors. Most important is the PHP configuration (based on the fact that you are working with CakePHP). The best place for the a test enviroment would be on the same server as the live application. You could maintain a live version and a test version and use symbolic links to the enviroment for switching the test to the live enviroment.

Comment: I'll try to take your advice in this as often as I can. I got the bad habbit of doing everything live due to several reasons.

Comment: I'll go with your solution of having a development enviroment. Thanks for the arguments!

Answer (score 1):

Do you use unit testing for the tests? [CakePHP does support that](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1196/Testing). When you are, you could [stub or mock](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.stubs) the data within your setup for the test. [Cake also supports that.](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1201/Preparing-test-data)

Comment: I don't know why, but I have a hard time understanding CakePHP's documentation.